# How to stop the errors in grpcurl within PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, grpcurl

I used grpcurl command line tool for grpc requests.
I include my grpc requests in PowerShell script.

when some requests have a failure statue PowerShell script will throw errors.

I want to block the errors from being shown in script's output.

I tried **-ErrorAction Stop** and **Try/Catch** methods but it doesn't work with grpc request.

here an example of my grpc request within the PowerShell script.

```
$GetParameters = grpcurl -plaintext -import-path <path> -proto service.proto <IP>:<port> descriptors./GetParameters
```

Comment: grpcurl isn't a powershell command.  Do you want to hide errors like `grpcurl 2>$null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to hide errors of external commands.  '2' is 'standard error'.

```
grpcurl 2>$null
```